# Binary tree arranged per bit of data, not by comparisons?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Suppose we use a binary tree just to store items that are just a series of bits. The top-level node's left node represents 0, right 1 for the least significant bit of the data:

```
Bit 1:  0     1
        |     |
Bit 2: 0  1  0 1
       |  |  | |
Bit 3:01 01 01 01
      ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^
Value:04 26 15 37
```

The advantage over the normal comparison-based node arrangement is that this way doesn't ever need rebalancing. Also the nodes may take up less space.

Is this a useful data structure, or is there a better version of it? Does it have a name?

Comment: It sounds like a [binary trie](https://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/13_1_digital_search_tree.html)

Comment: It doesn't need rebalancing so long as you get an even spread of numbers over the range, which is far from guaranteed. For instance, if data is often rounded to the nearest 10s place, you'll have a substantial skew factor. Rebalancing operations are often complex, but from what I recall they don't add much to algorithmic complexity, so it makes more sense to use the one-size-fits-all solution.

There might be niche applications where this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lee pointed out in the comments, this is closely related to a binary [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. You are correct that this implementation does not require any rebalancing to occur. In a BST, the shape of the tree is (more or less) independent of what's being stored in the tree, so you have to take precautions to ensure the tree doesn't become imbalanced. With a trie, the shape of the tree directly encodes what's stored in the trie, and no rebalancing is necessary.

Binary tries have a few disadvantages relative to, say, a balanced binary search tree. In particular, the storage requirements can be much higher; a binary tree holding n elements needs O(n log U) space, where U is the maximum value stored in the trie (O(log U) bits are needed to write it out). This can become a problem when you're storing a moderate number of large (64-bit, say) numbers. You can optimize the storage problem by using a [Patricia trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) (sometimes called a *radix trie*) by removing nodes that only have one child, though this requires a more clever implementation.

With some very clever optimizations on top of a binary tree, you can derive the [x-fast trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-fast_trie) and [y-fast trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie) data structures. The latter of these uses O(n) total storage and supports lookups in time O(log log U). This can be strictly better than a BST in theory, though in practice the constant factors hidden here aren't great.